# PHP7 MVC Echo not working - Mamp

Tags: php, model-view-controller, echo

Complete Noob. I'm trying to learn MVC. Going through this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRgHBu3msA4&index=4&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGXVHXX09fxXDi-DqInchFD

My Echo isn't printing on the screen.

Here's my code (99% the same as tutorial above)
Folder Structure
app
 -controllers
   -home.php
 -core
   -App.php
   -Controller.php
 -models
 -views
 -init.php
public
 -index.php
 -css

index.php

```
<?php
require_once '../app/init.php';

$app = new App;
```

init.php

```
<?php

require_once 'core/App.php';
require_once 'core/Controller.php';
```

App.php

```
<?php

class App
{
    protected $controller ='home';
    protected $method = 'index';

    protected $params = [];
    public function _construct()
    { 
        //$this->parseUrl();
        echo 'hi';
    }

    public function parseUrl()
    {
        if(isset($_Get['url'])){
            echo $_Get['url'];

        }
    }
}
```

Controller.php

```
<?php

class Controller
{

}
```

home.php

```
<?php
class Home extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
    echo 'home/index'
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use double underscore for constructors `__construct`

Comment: this will fail you `$_Get` and possibly `echo 'home/index'` no closing statement.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: and your question's a typo, off-topic.

Comment: @Fred-ii- help me understand. how was I off topic and what was my typo? Again noob - honest question. Also, I'm not seeing the issue with my '$_Get' and 'home/index'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Magic methods (and constructors) in PHP have to declared with double underscores. Otherwhise they are not recognices by the engine. So you have to change your App class to this:

```
<?php

class App
{
    // ...

    public function __construct() // !important: double underscore!
    { 
        echo 'hi';
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Philipp! Double underscore worked.

Comment: `$_Get` can't see how this would ever work though @LukeTrout if that's really what you're using.

Comment: Gotta love it when they put you on *"la la la, I don't hear you"* mode.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm here to learn. You told me it was wrong, not how to correct it.